# How to retrieve image data after confirmation on custom android camera

Tags: android, android-camera, out-of-memory

I'm attempting write a custom camera, have it all working, except 1 thing. I am trying to mimic the 'native' functionality where after you take a photo, it shows you a preview, and you have the choice to accept, redo, or cancel. I have this working.

The problem is that the **Camera.takePicture** callbacks happen right after the photo is taken, then I show this 'confirmation' screen. At this time the image is available to me, but I'm not ready for it...

I want to store the byte[] data in a temporary spot, until the user touches the 'confirm, I want to use this photo', THEN store the actual image on the device.

Currently I'm storing the image in a Bitmap like

```
// create the directory that the app uses to store pending
// uploads
String photoStoragePath = Environment
        .getExternalStorageDirectory()
        + Photo.UPLOAD_DIRECTORY;

// create the directory
File storageDirectory = new File(photoStoragePath);
storageDirectory.mkdirs();

// used for filename uid
long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();

// define the file_name to save photo taken by camera
// activity
String fileName = millis + ".jpg";

File file = new File(photoStoragePath, fileName);

// temporarily store the photo
mLastPhoto.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 95,
        new FileOutputStream(file.getAbsolutePath()));
```

But after taking 5 or so pictures I get this OOM Exception

```
09-26 01:55:14.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6303): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-26 01:55:14.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6303): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
09-26 01:55:14.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6303):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeByteArray(Native Method)
09-26 01:55:14.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6303):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:426)
09-26 01:55:14.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6303):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:444)
09-26 01:55:14.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6303):     at com.company.app.ui.CameraActivity$3$1$2.onPictureTaken(CameraActivity.java:203)
09-26 01:55:14.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6303):     at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:734)
09-26 01:55:14.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6303):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-26 01:55:14.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6303):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-26 01:55:14.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6303):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-26 01:55:14.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6303):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

Is it necessary to store the image in memory like this or is there something I'm missing that will make this easier?

Comment: if you are using any bitmaps recycle them by setting their object references to null after you complete using it

Comment: I set the mLastPhoto = null in a few spots where I know its no longer being used, so I'm either missing a spot or this isn't doing the job...

Comment: did you recycle it when the user presses the other button other than confirm?

Comment: I have not recycled it at all, I was afraid of what that might do to the references.. and I get the OOM having never pressed the 'cancel' button. BUT, I should be able to recycle if the user confirms, as the activity get finished, and when its recreated I allocate a new one -- that may be the issue..

Comment: Is the method I'm using here normal/acceptable?

Comment: I am not sure but do you have  any other button or something like it other than confirm? and if you do try to recycle it there using bitmap.recycle() because that might be the main reason as you are continuosly trying to use the bitmap object without recylcing it which is a dangerous act

Comment: The only places I can recycle are those where I'm finishing the activity, otherwise I cant use the bitmap anymore..

Comment: are you passing the same bitmap between activities or so?

Comment: It never leaves the activity. The callback from the camera sets the member variable, when the accept button is pressed, I save the data in the member variable.

Comment: what are the places where you used mLastPhoto = null then?

Comment: Well, I've replaced the two in the accept and cancel buttons with recycle, so there is only one now, and its right when the user presses the shutter button (before taking the photo). I don't initialize the Bitmap anywhere.. do I need to?

Comment: just try initialising with a null again. (just a guess)

Comment: No, it gets set to null before its used.. null isn't initialized..

Comment: Is the image getting stored if wou are not using the particular confirm dialog ?

Comment: confirm dialog? I get the impression you're not familiar with the standard camera within apps.. if you dont understand that it'll be hard to provide help with this question..

Comment: Well are you using the standard camera or creating a camera with the help of the surface view?
I am not that familiar with camera but i worked on it